# Systemd with Gitlab-runner and Manual commands works differently

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, gitlab

I have a python-based tg bot that is supposed to run as Systemd service. Service file goes as following.

```
[Unit]
Description=Telegram ImageBot
After=syslog.target
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
WorkingDirectory=/home/gitlab-runner/image-bot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/gitlab-runner/image-bot/new_imagebot.py
RestartSec=10
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I also have a script that performs a setup each time a gitlab-ci deploy being triggered.

```bash
#!/bin/sh

echo "========= IMAGE BOT SETUP =========="

sudo rm -rf /home/gitlab-runner/image-bot

sudo cp -r . /home/gitlab-runner/image-bot

sudo cp ./deploy/imagebot.service /etc/systemd/system

echo "========= SYSTEMCTL SETUP =========="

sudo systemctl daemon-reload

sudo systemctl enable imagebot.service

sudo systemctl start imagebot.service

sudo systemctl status imagebot.service
```

Python script should create some directories in order for it to work. And if I run service manually it creates them no problem. However, if `systemctl start imagebot.service` run in gitlab-runner it won't create any directory - bot goes down. What am I missing here? How can systemd service start differ by user?